# When running helm-buffers-list, after I start narrowing, how do I keep the ordering of the results by most recently used?

Tags: helm

When I run `helm-buffers-list`, I get a list of buffers, ordered by most recently used. This is great.

But when I start filtering that list, it sorts by buffer name length! So the top result may be a buffer that I haven't viewed in months!

#### to see this behavior:

1. Create a buffer `buf1`.
2. Create a buffer `thing2`.
3. Create a buffer `buffer3`.
4. Create a buffer `buff4`.
5. Now you should only have one window, and that buffer should be displaying `buff4`.
6. <kbd>M-x helm-buffers-list</kbd>. You should see:

```
buffer3
thing2
buf1
buff4
```

The buffers `*scratch*` and `*messages*` will be in there, but they're not relevant for this.

6. type <kbd>b</kbd>. Helm will show:

```
buf1
buff4
buffer2
```

Note that this is sorted by the *length* of the buffer name.

I would like it to show:

```
buffer3
buf1
buff4
```

These are all buffers with `b` in their names, sorted by most recently accessed, with the current buffer (`buff4`) at the end. This is the same sorting that `helm-buffers-list` does by default.

How can I sort it this way?